# Android R8 - Missing class: com.sun.javadoc.Doclet

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, androidx, android-r8

I'm using Android-R8 and the following R8-warnings are present:

**Missing class: com.sun.javadoc.Doclet**

the following image error,
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmkGY.png][1]

the application was build succesfully, but when it install it fails. Please help me how to fix it.

Comment: If it fails on installation, what is the error shown to you in Build bottom tab? Missing class: com.sun.javadoc.Doclet seems to be just warning.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by one of your dependencies using the type `com.sun.javadoc.Doclet`. That class does not exist on Android, and during R8 compilation this type will be missing and the warning is issued.

If you add the following line to your proguard rules configuration the waning should go away.

```
-dontwarn com.sun.javadoc.Doclet
```

The proguard rules configuration is specified in the app-level `build.gradle` file. The defualt is to use the file `proguard-rules.pro`.